# Can't access laravel page in vhost setup

Tags: php, apache, laravel, vhosts

I have a problem with the set up of laravel using a vhost. I have a different projects using vhost and it has no problem but when I try to set up this with Laravel I can't access it in my web browser. It just redirect to google page and searching for my vhost url.

So far here's what I did.

I included my vhost entry in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.laravel_validation.local
    ServerAlias dev.laravel_validation.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Web4/Desktop/laravel/laravel_validation/public"
    <Directory "C:/Users/Web4/Desktop/laravel/laravel_validation/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I include the name in Windows `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1      dev.laravel_validation.local
```

Then restart Wampserver. And I access the URL dev.laravel_validation.local to my browser but it doesn't display the Laravel's welcome page.

I don't know where did I go wrong. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Been a long time since I used WAMP but is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled in the httpd.conf

Comment: If it doesn't display the laravel welcome page, then what does it display? Further, your laravel installation is in your users directory, which I doubt that Apache has access to.

Comment: It just redirect to google page. I tried to transfer the file to the other path but same effect. What should I do to make my file accessible to apache?

Comment: You won't be able to access files outside of your public or www or htdocs directory unless you explicitly define the outside folder in you  apache2.conf [if it is there] or in your httpd.conf..